# Redis failure on CloudFoundry with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis, cloud-foundry

I'm making an app which uses Redis. It works perfectly on my computer running Ubuntu 12.04, but on CloudFoundry it gives me an error.

Here is the code for the app:

```
var
    http = require("http"),
    redis = require("redis"),
    cf = require("cloudfoundry");

cf.cloud;

if (cf.redis["myredisservice"]) {
    var rport = cf.redis["myredisservice"].credentials.port;
    var rhost = cf.redis["myredisservice"].credentials.hostname;
} else {
    var rport = 6379;
    var rhost = "127.0.0.1";
}


http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var client = redis.createClient(rport, rhost);

    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

    client.on("error", function(error) {
        res.write("Error: " + error);
    });

    res.write("Setting key 1<br>");
    client.set("key1", "My 1st String!", redis.print);

    res.write("Getting key1<br>");
    client.get("key1", function(error, reply) {
        res.write("Results for key1<br>");
        res.write(reply);
        client.end();
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(cf.port || 3000);
```

On CloudFoundry, when I run this app it gives me this output:

> Setting key 1
>
> Getting key1
>
> Error: Error: Ready check failed: ERR operation not permitted

I can confirm that its connecting to the Redis service using the port and hostname specified by CloudFoundry.

So I think its failing because of one of those commands. :(

Can anyone tell me, why is this error happening?

Thanks. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to authenticate to redis as well. Try this:

```
var
    http = require("http"),
    redis = require("redis"),
    cf = require("cloudfoundry");

cf.cloud;

if (cf.redis["myredisservice"]) {
    var rport = cf.redis["myredisservice"].credentials.port;
    var rhost = cf.redis["myredisservice"].credentials.hostname;
    var rpass = cf.redis["myredisservice"].credentials.password;
} else {
    var rport = 6379;
    var rhost = "127.0.0.1";
}


http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var client = redis.createClient(rport, rhost);
    client.auth(rpass);

    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

    client.on("error", function(error) {
        res.write("Error: " + error);
    });

    res.write("Setting key 1<br>");
    client.set("key1", "My 1st String!", redis.print);

    res.write("Getting key1<br>");
    client.get("key1", function(error, reply) {
        res.write("Results for key1<br>");
        res.write(reply);
        client.end();
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(cf.port || 3000);
```

Comment: Hey Glenn, Thanks a lot for the answer. It works flawlessly. :D

Comment: It would help newcomers, if you could make a guide to using Redis on CloudFoundry using NodeJS as you currently only have a guide using Ruby. :D

Comment: Glad to help! Check out http://blog.cloudfoundry.com next week (possibly the following) for some news about auto-configuration of services in node.js apps!

Comment: Arjun, that's a great suggestion and I'll point our node.js Developer Advocate at this thread so that he can think about doing that guide.